# Can I have server and client on the same machine and run network bandwidth test using iperf?

Tags: linux, networking, bash, bandwidth, iperf

I have two ethernet ports (eth0 and eth1) on my system. I've tested the bandwidth with two systems and got ~940Mbit/s. If I use one of the ports as server and the other as client, I always go through the internal loopback and get really high bandwidth. I read that it is possible to run server and client on the same system, but is it possible to get around the internal loopback and get a realistic measurement of the bandwidth using the two ports on the same system?